# hasattr(): attribute name must be string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to make a stacked bar plot in plotly using webscraping. However, I keep getting this error: "hasattr(): attribute name must be string". I think it might be the part:"gdp['IMF[1][13]', 'Estimate']" that is causing the error.

This is what the dataframe looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOwCQ.png)

```
import plotly.express as px
ERROR -> fig = px.bar(gdp, x = gdp['UN Region'], y = gdp['IMF[1][13]', 'Estimate'], color = gdp['Country/Territory'])
fig.show()
```

Comment: Please post your data in text format, not as a screenshot, so that we can reproduce your problem. You can run `gdp.head(10).to_dict()` (also see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391)). Also post your full error traceback message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
fig = px.bar(gdp, x = gdp['UN Region', 'UN Region'],
                  y = gdp['IMF[1][13]', 'Estimate'],
                  color = gdp['Country/Territory', 'Country/Territory'])
```